# Does accessing methods in a non static way affect/benefit performance?

Tags: java, performance, static

Assuming all method calls here are static, like this:

```
public class Util {
    public static void method1() {
    }
}
```

Accessing in a static way:

```
Util.method1();
Util.method2();
Util.method3();
```

accessing in a non static way

```
Util util = new Util();
util.method1();
util.method2();
util.method3();
```

Is there any performance difference for either way?  I know the first way of doing it here is accessing it properly. But the second way only instantiates the util object once as opposed to three times.  I can't find anything pointing to anything other than to be accessing these methods properly.  From what I can tell there is no functional difference, but a logical difference.  Looking for sort of a cost vs. benefit of either way if anyone knows.

Comment: All I know is that if you create static methods more often than non static ones the java code stops looking like object-oriented but like that of a procedural language (i.e. C)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is there any performance difference for either way?

Yes - the second is marginally slower, due to a pointless instance being constructed.

> I know the first way of doing it here is accessing it properly. But the second way only instantiates the util object once as opposed to three times.

No, the second way creates one instance of `Util` whereas the first way doesn't create *any* instances.

The first way is *significantly* better, because it makes it clear that it *is* a static method. Consider this code:

```
Thread t = new Thread(someRunnable);
t.start();
t.sleep(1000);
```

What does it look like that last call does? Surely it makes the new thread sleep, right? No... it just calls `Thread.sleep()`, which only ever makes the *current* thread sleep.

When you mangle a static method call to act "through" a reference, the value of the reference is completely ignored - it can even be null:

```
Util util = null;
util.method1(); // This will still work...
```

Comment: "*the second is marginally slower.*" - this can't be right, can it? I'd bet, `javac` generates `invokestatic` and if you could fool it to generate `invokevirtual`, you'd get `NoSuchMethodError` as the virtual dispatch ignores static methods. UPDATE: Looking at your comment, I see that you mean "slower because of the pointless instance creation", not "because of the non-static call". Could you make it explicit in your answer?

Comment: @maaartinus: Done... although it didn't require reading *much* further in the answer...

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference for the code you show, since all those methods are static.  (The compiler will issue a warning for the second group, however.)  I *think* there's a small performance benefit to static methods.  The underlying byte code for static access, invokeSpecial I think, should be faster than invokeVirtual, which has to do some type decoding.

But it's not enough to worry about.  Use whichever type of method (static vs. instance) is right for your design.  Don't try to optimize the method calls like that.

Comment: It won't call `invokeVirtual` anyway. The only difference in the byte code for the second way is that it will create a pointless instance of `Util`, and then ignore it.

Comment: Well, it would if a method was an instance method, which is what I was referring too.  The OP did ask about virtual methods, so I was trying to explain a bit how they work.

Comment: No, the OP didn't ask about virtual methods at all. The question *starts* with "Assuming all method calls here are static" and the first occurrence of "virtual" on the page is this answer...